# Putting a label on a link

Tags: html, checkbox, hyperlink, menu, label

**So my Question is as following:**

I have this HTML code extract of an mobile side menu:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="activator" class="activator" name="menu">
  <div class="toplayer"></div>


  <label for="activator" class="activator" name="menu">
   <img class="icon" src="../media/menu_new.png" alt="Menu">
  </label>


  <div class="menu">

  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
     <input type="checkbox" id="d1" class="subtivator" name="submenu">
     <div class="dropdown"><label for="d1"><span class="submenu">...</span></label></div>
     <div class="drawer">
      <label for="activator" class="activator" name="menu"><a href="#">...</a></label>
```

And what I wanna do is that if you click on the link in the last line, the parental label triggers the checkbox from the first line, so that the whole menu gets closed automaticaly.
The link itself works, but the menu just stays open because the checkbox won't get triggered by the label. If you run the code snippet, you can clearly see that there is a trigger animation for the checkbox, but it just does not CHANGE. If you remove the "href"-attribute on the -tag, it suddenly works. The label ist 100% identical to the label from line 6 which I used to actually open up and close the menu.
I also already looked up a few references, but none of them had any restrictions regarding the -tag and -tag.
I just can't figure out where the error is located and, of course, can't fix it because of that.

I really hope some of you guys can help me out with this a little bit.

Thanks in advance

Comment: the href reloads your page and thats why the checkbox gets unchecked and you basically only want to close the menu as I understood, or do you want to navigate away or to a new page? maybe instead of an anchor tag and href, use a onclick and trigger it with jquery or javascript.

Comment: Well, I just wan't to close a mobile side menu which takes about half the screen because it's annoying when you have to close it manually all the time.
The anchor is there because in the menu you can navigate on the current page, using #[id]. May great goal by the way is not to use anything other than html and css